# Story about a man (teacher) having an affair

Tags: identification-request

I have forgotten the title of a book I read around 10 years ago. The book was fairly old then. The setting was in times of horses, carriages and telegrams. It consisted of a gentleman who went to stay as a live-in teacher for 2 children and fell for their mother. The father had traveled a lot and became disabled (due to a shooting incident or something) and used to drink a lot. He generally wasn't a nice guy.

There was also a cleaning maid (who helped to hide the affair) named Horton. And a family doctor who used to come visit. I think the man (teacher) used to write to his sister named Aggy or Agatha. Eventually the wife kills the husband (by poisoning or some sort). Some lines I remember and can paraphrase:

> No doubt find Horton stretched across the threshold.
>
> The doctor is blowing smoke, and he is fanning it this way.

This was during pre-Google times, and all search terms I used did not produce any close results.

Comment: Can you give any more detail? What country is the book set in, what part of that country? Was it written in the period it's set in or closer to the time you read it? You said it was 'fairly old' then, 5 years, twenty, fifty, two hundred?

Comment: @Spagirl It had a country setting, maybe London. I don't think it had American settings. It was probably written in or very close to the same period it was set in. I said fairly old because i read it in old paperback book (the front cover was gone.. and there was no back cover as well) but it may have been 30 - 40 years old.. Just a guess.

Comment: I'm confused, the *physical copy* you read was 40 years old but it was written much longer ago, pre-motor cars?

Comment: @Spagirl yes that is correct. Sorry, what's the confusing part? I'll try my best to clear it.

Comment: Well it was possible to read it as you thinking that 50 years ago was the age of horses and telegrams!